# p4python fetch_, run_ and save_ command

Tags: p4python

The fetch_spec, run_spec and save_spec commands look useful, but they omit
the -f option in the command, which means you can only run it on your own specs.
If you're managing a DB for a large group and need to add/delete users,groups,clients,etc., how do you make use of these commands?

Answer (score 2):

P4Python is flexible for such commands. One option is to use the actual command as the string, instead of the shortcuts:

```
p4.run(spec + ' -f ' + name)
```

You can also benefit from the *args* parameter of that `run` function. For example you can use the below commands interchangably (more info: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.run).

```
clientspec = p4.fetch_client('clientname')
clientspec = p4.run('client', '-o', '-f', 'clientname')[0]
```

Another option is to make use of the options of shortcuts (as in this example: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.delete_spectype ). Though, for this one you might need to check from the documentation about which shortcut accepts arguments.

```
p4.delete_client( '-f', 'client')
```